# OTA Ad Hoc Distribution fails without any response

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, over-the-air

I created an install page for beta testers. This link to the `manifest.plist` is valid and is via HTTPS.

However when I click the link nothing happens. No alert or no errors or messages appear in the device logs.

Does anybody know this issue?

**EDIT I** Everything is setup correctly and *should* work. All URLs are correct and accessible and the server has a trusted, valid certificate bought from `Thawte`. I think the server is set up correctly, another project installs correctly from the same server.

Comment: Some more detail maybe?

Comment: Sure. What details you'd like to know? I didn't know what else to write...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the issue. The IPA file name contained a space.
As I removed the space it immediately worked like charm!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I was searching for the issue for like hours and I thought spaces were not a problem. But obviously they are. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It might help to see the associated plist contents, HTML source...etc but I'll list a few common situations you might want to review:

1. Make sure your HTML source has the correct URL. Here is an example of what it should look like: `itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=[URL of PLIST]`
2. Make sure your mime-types are setup correctly. For example, if you are using Apache Httpd check to make sure this is in your httpd.conf file: `AddType application/octet-stream .ipa`
3. Check the URLs in the plist and make sure they are accessible.
4. Make sure your server CA Authority cert is installed on the devices. You can email it to the device (PEM file), and press on the attachment.

Also, I would check the server logs and see if the IPA is even being retrieved.

Comment: You only need #4 if you self sign your ssl cert.

Comment: See my update, according to this list, I shouldn't have a problem. Nevertheless, if I would have certificate issues or similar, I would have gotten a warning, this is not the case.